# Is there a definitive list of Button Men rules?

Tags: button-men

There are many, **many** Button Men dice rules. I'm trying to find a list of them with easy to understand examples.

I'm not new to the game, but I keep coming across dice I've never heard of (like Rage and Mighty). I would like to find an easy way to look up dice.

I'm sure [Buttonweavers](http://buttonweavers.com/) has a list **somewhere**, but I can't find it. I've done some digging through the forums, but it's not as easy to navigate as most that I've used.

Comment: The verbiage at http://beatpeopleup.cheapass.com/game-rules/ seems to imply that the dice lists on that page are complete.

Comment: I found [this](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17/button-men/files) yesterday. The rules have more than the Cheapass Game page but don't have all the skills that are available on [Buttonweavers](http://buttonweavers.com). Maybe they're unofficial skills?

Anyway, thank you for your answer. I appreciate you looking that up.

Comment: @SteveB: could you post your answer as an answer rather than as a comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verbiage at beatpeopleup.cheapass.com/game-rules seems to imply that the dice lists on that page are complete.

Comment: As a follow up, what I thought were official skills were, in fact, unofficial skills implemented on the Buttonweaver website. There are quite a few.

Answer (score -2):

There's an extensive, though still incomplete, list at https://github.com/buttonmen-dev/buttonmen/wiki/Tester-guide:-supported-skills

Answer (score -4):

https://buttonmen.fandom.com/wiki/Buttonmen_Wiki has about 90% of all die skills.